# It is not looping through answers correctly?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query below with a dynamic where clause where it outputs results depending on drop down menus selected. Now the where clause works correctly in adding and removing certain conditions depending on the options selected.

But what I have kind of realised is that if I want to look at all questions, it doesn't have the `QuestionId = ?` condition which is fine, but when it is suppose to display the answers for each question, instead of displaying it like this:

```
D (this is for question 1)
B,C,E (this is for question 2)
```

It is displaying them all as one answer like below which is incorrect:

```
D,B,C,E
```

My question is what is causing this, the query or the loop?

The var_dump($questions): displays this:

`array(1) { [39]=> array(1) { [72]=> array(1) { ["answer"]=> string(7) "B,C,D,E" } } }`

72 is QuestionId, so for some strange reason it is not going through all questions (there should be a second question which is 73)

Below is code:

```
    $selectedstudentanswerqry = "
            SELECT sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId,
            GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer
            FROM Student st
            INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (st.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
            INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
            INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
            ";

            // Initially empty
            $where = array('q.SessionId = ?');
            $parameters = array($_POST["session"]);
            $parameterTypes = 'i';


            //check if POST is empty

            // Check whether a specific student was selected
            $p_student = empty($_POST["student"])?'':$_POST["student"];

            switch($p_student){
            case 0:
                //dont' add where filters
                break;
            default:
                $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
                $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
                $parameterTypes .= 'i';
            }

            // Check whether a specific question was selected
            $p_question = empty($_POST["question"])?'':$_POST["question"];

            switch($p_question){
            case 0:
                //dont' add where filters
                break;
            default:
                $where[] = 'q.QuestionId = ?';
                $parameters[] .= $_POST["question"];
                $parameterTypes .= 'i';
            }

            // If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
            // our query
            if(!empty($where)) {
                $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
                global $mysqli;
                $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
                // You only need to call bind_param once

                if (count($where) == 1) {
                $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0]);
            }
            else if (count($where) == 2) {
                $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1]);
            }
            else if (count($where) == 3) {
                $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1], $parameters[2]);
            }

            }

            $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
              GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
              ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId
            ";

        // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->execute(); 
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentId,$detailsQuestionId,$detailsAnswer);   

        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->store_result();
        $selectedstudentanswernum = $selectedstudentanswerstmt->num_rows(); 

    $questions = array();

    while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {

        $questions[$detailsStudentId][$detailsQuestionId] = array(

        'answer'=>$detailsAnswer,

);

}

...

<?php   

var_dump($questions);

        foreach ($questions as $studentId => $student)
{

foreach ($student as $questionId => $question) {

echo '<p><strong>Answer:</strong> ' .htmlspecialchars($question['answer']).  '</p>' . PHP_EOL;

}

}

?>
```

Comment: I do not see anything that could effect your outcome except this line               `GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId` try to delete it and see the results that you get

Comment: @shnisaka No it did not work, I will post a screenshot on what is shows in query. Actually what I will do is paste the query result as a sample and then ask how the loop should be written. Do you fancy the challenge?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is actually the:

```
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer
```

part of the query.  Without seeing actual table structure and data it's very hard to form a mental image of what's going on.  "Answer" may be an ambiguous column and thus cause unpredictable results.

You might consider writing a subquery or creating a view for this.

```
SELECT sa.StudentID, q.QuestionId, sa.Student_Answers
FROM (
     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.Answer SEPERATOR ',') as Question_Answers
     FROM Student_Answer a
     GROUP BY a.QuestionID
) AS sa
INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
```

Looking at your code, there doesn't seem to be a need to join the Students table as the ID already exists in their answers.  Though I'm sure at some point you will associate names with ID's.